# "QtCore4.dll Access Violation" on QGIS custom plugin C++

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have developed a custom QGIS plugin (dll) using C++ through QTCreator. All compiles fine but when I try to activate this plugin in QGIS it crashes and a minidump is created.

After some investigations on the minidump, I am getting this :

```
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS_c0000005_QtCore4.dll!Unknown

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 5fe6d5a0 (QtCore4+0x0009d5a0)
ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
```

Here is my .pro for the QT project :

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = MyApp2CPP
QT += core gui sql xml

DEFINES += QT_DLL QT_SQL_LIB MYAPPCPP_LIB QT_XML_LIB

win32:CONFIG(Release, Debug|Release)
{
    LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/lib -lQtCore4
    LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/lib -lQtGui4
    LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/lib -lQtXml4
    LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/lib -lQtSql4
    LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-dev/lib -lqgis_core
    LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-dev/lib -lqgis_gui
}

win32:CONFIG(Debug, Debug|Release)
{
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += C:/OSGeo4W/lib/QtCored4.lib
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += C:/OSGeo4W/lib/QtGuid4.lib
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += C:/OSGeo4W/lib/QtXmld4.lib
    LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/lib/ -lQtCored4
    LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/lib/ -lQtGuid4
    LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/lib/ -lQtXmld4
    LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-dev/lib -lqgis_core
    LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-dev/lib -lqgis_gui
}

win32:
{
    INCLUDEPATH += C:/OSGeo4W/include
    DEPENDPATH += C:/OSGeo4W/include
    INCLUDEPATH += C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-dev/include
    DEPENDPATH += C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-dev/include
}

...
```